# LibreOffice 4.1 failing - Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: libreoffice

The menus in LibreOffice 4.1 have stopped working properly. They still drop down when I hover over them, yet only a few of the options are available - none of them that I need, such as formatting options.

Comment: Can you share a screenshot?

Comment: I'm not smart enough to do that, Seth. PrtSc is the only way I know to capture a screenshot. To show that all the menu options are grayed-out (unavailable), I must hover the cursor over them, but when I hit PrtSc it removes the drop down menus from the screen.

Comment: you can take a screenshot with the program Kazam : it can wait a few seconds then take a screenshot, it's useful for this kind of screenshot, because then you have the time to reclick on the menu. To install it, open a terminal and type `sudo apt-get install kazam`, or search for Kazam in the Ubuntu Software Center.

Comment: @user242256 There is a program pre-installed called "Screenshot", try using that with a delay.

Comment: Seth is right. You can enter the command : `gnome-screenshot --delay=seconds` (replace `seconds` by a number), I wasn't aware of that !

Answer (score 1):

1) You can try to reinstall LibreOffice :

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall libreoffice
```

---

2) You can try to uninstall completely LibreOffice, then reinstall it :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge libreoffice*
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

---

3) You can try to install a newer version of libreoffice :

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:libreoffice/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libreoffice
```

Comment: I tried all three with reboot and the problem remains. I've only had Ubuntu for a few days, and I'm not the most knowledgeable person with computers, so it's possible I've just jacked something up without realizing it.

Comment: Normally (and especially if you have tried all 3 options), these commands would correct all your problems related to LibreOffice. In my opinion, your problem comes from another thing than LibreOffice...

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.